# Which encoding should I use for my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, character-encoding

I had a problem similar to this one: [Android Studio 1.2 - Project encoding mismatches by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012529/android-studio-1-2-project-encoding-mismatches-by-default)

The Android Studio project & gradle encoding is now set to windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

Is there any reason I should be using one of these over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since gradle and Android studio both use UTF-8, you should consider using that. It's a good encoding too as it's based on unicode charset.

There has also been some talk on whether they should enforce UTF-8 or not in the future, so you should start changing to UTF-8 asap :)

You can change your encoding as follows below.

Click **File -> Settings (or click Ctrl + Alt + S)  and find File Encodings** in your Androd Studio. See the image below as a reference.

Now you have three options

- change UTF-8 to match other encoding
- or change project encoding to match UTF-8 since both Gradle and
  Android Lint use this (recommended)
- Ignore the warning

[image]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/3V/p7/5xt1uxV/encoding.png))</sub>

You can also see the current encoding of your file at the bottom right corner of Android studio. You can also change it there. See the image below. 
[image: IDE Encoding]

Answer (score 1):

Localization to numerous languages requires Unicode, so use UTF-8.

BTW, it is possible that due to this reasoning nobody never tested the development environment with a non-Unicode encoding.