# Serious Android Studio update issues

Tags: android, android-studio, auto-update

I had been working on **Android Studio version 1.1**. 2-3 days before, it asked for update to 1.2. I thought it was gonna get all the better. But, now I am facing the following problems:

```
Warning:The project encoding (windows-1252) does not match the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8).
This can lead to serious bugs.
<a href="http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding">More Info...</a><br><a href="open.encodings.settings">Open File Encoding Settings</a>
```

and,

```
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio
```

I have tried uninstalling-reinstalling it like 7 time already but problems don't go away. I have never messed up with Android Studio settings.

Why is this happening? and What should I do to resolve it? I am just enough desperate that I was gonna Format my computer but thats a mammoth task so I am asking here.

**P.S:** I tried changing the encoding but nothing works.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1 :** Following Sandspy's advice `build.gradle` contains the following with no support library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mankum93.geoquiz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Here is the problem still persisting:
[image: [img]http://i.imgur.com/yXNX2TT.png[/img]]

**EDIT 3:** After changing from MNC to Android Lollipop.
[image]

**EDIT 4:** I guess I am gonna download the 1.2 stable binary and not update until 1.3 stable is released. If anyone solves this problem concretely please post the solution here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012529/android-studio-1-2-project-encoding-mismatches-by-default check this. same issue.

Comment: @Shvet : First issue is gone but the second issue still remains

Comment: Latest SDK tool is 24.3 which will need new update for android studio.

Comment: @Shvet : I had a hell of a good time with ADT plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For any reason, Android Studio generates the projects in windows-1252 enconding, but the IDE enconding still being UTF-8.
You can change it in File -> Settings -> Editor -> File encoding -> Project Encoding; like weston said in the last answer.

For reference, the same issue was answered in this sites:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012572
- http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding
- http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=396&t=9107&start=20

Answer (score 0):

Though not a solution to the problem, I have  tried uninstalling-reinstalling Android 1.1.2, 1.2 again and again. I then tried tried Android 1.1. Now, everything is working perfectly.
So, I am saying is, people having this problem might have to rely on Android Studio 1.1 for now. I am posting it to tell you of a tricky step involved in thi process. If you have Android 1.2.1 or 1.2 installed, after the uninstallation of it, delete the following folder,

`<Your-current-PC-user-Name>/.AndroidStudio` or `/.AndroidStudio11.2` and `/.gradle` before reinstallation of Android 1.1 otherwise problem will persist.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this:

[image: Issue]

Click Open File Encoding Settings and change from windows-1252 to UTF-8:

[image: Alter File Encodings]